# Hide service bus implementation behind interfaces

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, interface, autofac

I'm currently working on a project that allows 3rd parties to hook into our product's message broker.  The task is to provide a library that these 3rd parties can consume.  I want to be able to package either Mass Transit or NServiceBus along with it but I want to hide that detail behind interfaces.

I've got the service bus itself hidden like this...

```
public class MyServiceBus : IServiceBus {

  private readonly MassTransit.IBus _bus;
  private readonly MassTransit.IBusControl _busControl;

  public PanelSawServiceBus(MassTransit.IBus bus, MassTransit.IBusControl busControl) {
     _bus = bus;
     _busControl = busControl;
  }

  public Task PublishAsync<T>(T message, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class =>
     _bus.Publish(message, token);

  public Task SendAsync<T>(T message, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken)) where T : class =>
     (_bus as ISendEndpointProvider)?.Send(message, token);

  public Task StartAsync() => _busControl.StartAsync();
  public Task StopAsync() => _busControl.StopAsync();
}
```

A vendor should not be allowed to publish/send messages and should only be consuming.  How can I hide consumption of the messages so I can package a service bus library and not expose what library is being used under the covers?

**Edit 1**
Consuming a message with Mass Transit looks like this

```
public class MyConsumer : IConsumer<SomeMessage> {
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SomeMessage> ctx) => Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

During bootstrapping when you are creating a service bus instance you can define your consumers (Mass Transit will construct them when a message comes in for you).

```
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingInMemory(config => {
    config.ReceiveEndpoint("queue_name", endpointCfg => {
        endpointCfg.Consumer<MyConsumer>();
    }
};
```

What I'd like the wrapper to do is allow the developer to say "Using a queue factory I want to construct an instance with *this* queue name and here are the names of the types that implement the consumer interface that is hiding the bus technology's interfaces."  I just don't know if I can hide the consumers.

Comment: Small comment regarding wrapping around MassTransit, like you do in this example. Publishing directly from `IBus` is generally ill-advised. Instead you might want to inject `IPublishEndpoint` when possible and use `ConsumeContext` in the consumers. https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#publish

Comment: @Slowacki I agree.  I was also thinking, over time, that it might be fine to abstract the implementation away from sending/publishing but keep the consumers specific to the tech being used.  You should be injecting the rules of your app into consumers anyway.  Since you shouldn't have business rules in the consumers it should be fine implementing tech-specific interfaces for message consumption.

Comment: That's what I decided to do with the app I'm currently working on. Abstracted out the publishing and sending, but kept the consumers as-is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to keep your code from being coupled to either NServiceBus or MassTransit, and you don't want to expose which one you are using.

**First, the decoupling:**
You've accomplished part of this by defining your own `IServiceBus` interface. As long as your library depends only on that interface and not on any implementation, you shouldn't be coupled to either.

To ensure that you avoid such coupling, I'd keep concrete implementations in separate projects/libraries. Your "core" domain should not directly reference either. If you can unit test the code without either concrete implementation present then you're free to switch between implementations.

When you publish your library you can publish the composition of your core library along with the implementations of its interfaces that you have selected.

**Then, hiding which implementation is used:**
As for not exposing whether you use `NServiceBus` or `MassTransit`, you can't. If someone references your library and it depends on one of those packages, they'll have to add that package too. Assuming that your library is packaged for NuGet, that package will reveal its dependencies.

Comment: I'm definitely expecting to package whatever tech is being used with what we send.  Only issue I'm having right now is with hiding from my business rules the consumers.  Mass Transit has an IConsumer<T> interface that you tack onto your consumer class.  Can I do the same with the consumers that I did with the service bus?

Comment: I'm a bit limited because I'm not familiar with how MassTransit is used. In principle (which may or may not be helpful) you would ensure that within your core library you depend only on your own interfaces defined within that library. Any classes that must reference MassTransit's interfaces would be a part of that implementation, separate from the core library.

Comment: I edited the question to include a little detail about how consumers are written and how to tell Mass Transit about your consumers.